# Lambda function – GET doesn't return anything

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

I am completely new to The Serverless Framework and AWS lambda.

When making a GET request to http://localhost:3000/user/1e89a3f0-d170-11e9-94bd-91e9ae84f3e9 I would expect a response being send back to the browser with a valid JSON object matching the Key. Like the only getting logged out to the console. And not empty document.

Am I returning incorrectly? I am having difficulties debugging this, I don’t now if the problem is with my lambda function, or what it is.

Thank you.

**`console.log` statement**

```
{
  email: 'i@am.com',
  password: '$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$IIICgcMqbUA7wFpEMqb/GA$ENScjko+Y8pruQsTiE6qN81QAJfAPX/T116RQZqe347Y1p0rez4KhKaEulMeabKKiu8',
  id: '1e89a3f0-d170-11e9-94bd-91e9ae84f3e9'
}
```

Here is the get handler in question.

**users/get.js**

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: "localhost",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

module.exports.get = async event => {
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Key: {
      id: event.pathParameters.id
    }
  };

  dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log(result.Item); // logs successfully to the console.
    return {
      // doesn't return a response.
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result.Item)
    };
  });
};
```

**serverless.yml**

```
# EXCERPT

functions:
  get:
    handler: users/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: user/{id}
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    UsersDynamoDbTable:
      Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}

custom:
  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - dev
    start:
      port: 8000
      inMemory: true
      sharedDb: true
      noStart: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use the callback argument to return a response:

```
module.exports.get = (event, context, callback) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Key: {
      id: event.pathParameters.id,
    },
  };

  dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback({
        statusCode: 500,
        body: 'Unable to get item',
      });
    }
    console.log(result.Item);

    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result.Item),
    });
  });
};
```

Or use promises:

```
module.exports.get = async event => {
  try {
    const params = {
      TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
      Key: {
        id: event.pathParameters.id,
      },
    };

    const result = await dynamoDb.get(params).promise();
    console.log(result.Item);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result.Item),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: 'Unable to get item',
    };
  }
};
```